# How can I set the Windows command line to use the php.ini file?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, php

I have [EasyPHP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyPHP) 5.3.6.0 local server, (with PHP 5.3.6) and it works fine in my browser. However, using the PHP executable on the command line doesn't work without problems.

I have noticed that command line didn't load the *php.ini* file:

```html
C:\\> php --ini
```

Output:

```html
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Btw, there isn’t a *php.ini* file in the 'C:\Windows' directory. My server (apparently) uses the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\apache\php.ini' file.

When I translate PHP files I get a warning:

> Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You
> are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case
> you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled th
> e timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Helsinki' for '3.0/DST' instead in C:\Program Files (x86)
> \EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\home\timezone.inc.php on line 2

I got no warnings when I used the 'php -c ...' command, but I'd like permanently set an .ini file to use with a command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php` is just saying that's where it expects the `php.ini` file to be. One option is to copy the ones from the web server and modify them as necessary.

Comment: This solved all my problems. I copied the ini file used by my server to 'Windows' directory. I tried this once before, but copied a wrong ini file. Now I can use yii-framework's 'yiic shell' command too. Thanks!